# Detecting WebView2 vs standalone Edge browser?

Tags: javascript, webview, microsoft-edge, browser-detection, webview2

I have a page that needs to render differently depending on whether it's being viewed from a WebView2 component (inside another application) or from a standalone Microsoft Edge browser. I tried distinguishing the two via the user agent string, but the strings are more or less identical (both contain "Edg"). Does anyone have a method to distinguish between a WebView2 and an Edge browser?

Comment: If your own app is opening the page then you can indicate that in the search parameters: `https://example.com/?target=webview2`.

Comment: The user agents are the same for WebView2 and Edge browser. If you're the owner of the WebView2 app, you can [set a new user agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings.useragent?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1185.39) for it. Otherwise, it seems there's no other way to distinguish between WebView2 and Edge browser.

Comment: You have not even said, whether you it's your application, you want to change or if you need to generally detect browser (on the server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no perfect way for web content to identify that is running within a WebView2 because the host app of the WebView2 can customize so many aspects of the WebView2.

For example, the host app can change the user agent via `CoreWebView2Settings.UserAgent` to appear to be Chrome or any other browser. Or the host app can inject script using `CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync` and change the DOM or other objects in script.

However, if you are trying to determine if your web content is running within your own app, you can use those same customizations I mention above as a way for the host app to signal to the web content that the web content is running within a WebView2.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this question a bit late, apparently, but there's a very specific way to detect WebView2 because the engine injects several members into the window object, including iFrames. For example, the method window.gc is something that won't normally exist, but let's see what happens in a WebView2 engine:

```js
if ("gc" in window) alert("WebView2");
```

[image: Detecting WebView2]

If you don't want to check the main window. you can do it from an emtpy iFrame, which will return true as well.